# How to create a timer thread in c

Tags: c, multithreading, timer, pthreads

How to create a timer thread function : timerThreadFunction(pthread_t thread_id), and check the result of the timer in a safe manner from other function:

```
    // Begin of atomic part -- cause i'm in multithreaded environement
    if (timerThreadFunction(thread_id) has not expired) {
        // SOME WORK HERE
    }

    else {

    // Timer expired
    // some work here

    }

// End of atomic part
```

THANKS.

Comment: Since C has no native threading library, you'll have to tell us what platform you're on so we can suggest that. I also suggest retagging your question to indicate the platform as well. Lest you be bombarded with answers for platforms you're not interested in.

Comment: @jer: The mention of `pthread_t` in the question seems to imply the Pthreads library.

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking about the mutual exclusion part, you can use a mutex to accomplish that.  Use [pthread_mutex_init to initialize a mutex and pthread_mutex_destroy](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutex_init) to clean it up.  Then use [pthread_mutex_lock and pthread_mutex_unlock](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutex_lock) to obtain and release the mutex.

**Edit** Based on a brief (extremely brief) look at your other post that you mention in the comments, I understand you are looking for an alternative to sleep().  One possibility is to use [select()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/select).  The do something like this:

```
struct timeval sleeptime;
// initialize sleeptime with the desired length such as
memset( &sleeptime, 0, sizeof( sleeptime ));
sleeptime.tv_sec = 5;

select( 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, &sleeptime );
```

That won't block the other threads.  You should note, though, that `select` will return (if I remember correctly) if the process receives any signals even if the time is not yet up.

Comment: Thanks, but i want some tips and some sample code on how to that, i googled a lot and ther's no timer thread example.

Comment: @evariste, For the mutex examples, google's first hit [is this site](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialPosixThreads.html), which seems reasonable.  Can you define what you are looking for when you say "timer thread"?  If it has a common meaning, I am not familiar with it.

Comment: Thanks, i posted some code here but it cannot be used in multithreaded environnement: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4695038/thread-timer-in-c

Comment: Thanks but select behaves like sleep it blocks until the timer expiration, i comment sleep() in my previous code and added your suggest like this: struct timeval sleeptime;
 // initialize sleeptime with the desired length such as
 memset( &sleeptime, 0, sizeof( sleeptime ));
 sleeptime.tv_sec = seconds;
 select( 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, &sleeptime );

Comment: @evariste, I don't have time to study your other question now - sorry about that.  But I do know with 100% certainty that `select` does not block other threads from running.  That function is used for detecting input on sockets, files, pipes, etc.  It is used extensively in myriad applications that do not stop processing while waiting for a packet on a socket.  So I'm guessing there must be something else going on.  If I have time later, I will take a look.

Comment: Thanks but it blocks for sure :), at least in my case.

Comment: @evariste: `sleep()` and `select()` block the thread that called those functions - they do not block other threads.

Comment: In my case, when you run the program just one thread can execute, other threads not. I want a non blocking tips?

Comment: @evariste, I took a moment to look at the code you referenced in your other post.  In that code, you are holding the mutex while calling the sleep function.  This means that one thread would get the mutex, do whatever atomic operation it needs, and then call the sleep function.  The other two threads will wait until the first thread releases the mutex, which means they will wait during the entire sleep period.

Answer (score 0):

There are loads of options

1. Don't use a separate thread, just poll some internal timer.
2. let your timer thread complete and join your main thread to the timer thread.
3. Use a semaphore
4. Use a mutex protected flag.

That should be enough to get you started.